# Make a promise on React Table in getTrProps method

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Im trying to make a promise inside my `react-table` component in the method `getTrProps`. The problem is that I get this warning and It cant load the subcomponent. `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.`

My code:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

 componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true 
  }


<ReactTable

   getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => {
                return {
                      axios.get('my get url').then(resp => {
                        console.log('this._isMounted', this._isMounted)
                        if(this._isMounted) {
                          this.setState(resp.data)
                        }
                      })
                  },
                  style: {
                    background: rowInfo.index === this.state.selected ? '#00afec' : 'white',
                    color: rowInfo.index === this.state.selected ? 'white' : 'black'
                  }
                }
            }}

/>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should not be using `this._isMounted`; instead, you can save the reference to the promise, and `cancel` the request in `componentWillUnmount` instead.

Comment: Yes, here is reference to the documentation - https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html. I also think it will not solve your problem.